# redefining or overriding metaestimators in sklearn?

Tags: python, pandas, oop, scikit-learn

I am writing a custom `sklearn` pipeline.

I need it to be able to process `pandas` dataframes.
If I create custom transformers and estimators by creating child classes of the built-in

```
BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin,TransformerMixin
```

all these classes automatically cast the dataframes to numpy.ndarray during the fit/transform function, when `_check_X_y` is called precisely.

I am aware of the existence of https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas, however depending on an unstable binding between two unstable libraries is not an option.

Therefore I have implemented my estimators without inheriting anything from `BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin, TransformerMixin` but just defining the methods requested by the api `fit(),fit_transform(),transform(),_get_params(),_set_params()`.
To me, it seems this works perfectly, also in combination with `GridSearchCV`.

I can just convert the `df` to `numpy` only when needed

My question is: is there any reason why I should not be doing this?
Do I miss any hidden sklearn API requirement?